# How to format date from string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have a string with this value:

```
2010-05-13 23:17:29
```

I'd like to format it and am using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSDate *formattedDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
[formatter release];
```

When the debugger reaches the release line, formattedDate shows "invalid CFStringRef" and

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `dateString` properly initialized?

Comment: Is dateString being released? What is the retain count? Is it an autoreleased object? If so you need to retain it.

Answer (score 7):

`dateFromString` is returning `nil` because it couldn't parse the string containing the date and time. This is because `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` specifies a date format like "May 16, 2010" (it actually varies depending on the locale and user settings). This format doesn't match your string.

To parse your string you should set a [`dateFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDateFormat:) instead of the `dateStyle`, for example:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: That works.  In the above format, how do I display am/pm and time zone?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your string is already released.

I also suspect that your date string isn't in the correct format for the formatter, which will give you a null date.